# How to run specific winform inside one solution in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

In my solution, I have two projects...
One for my main application and the other for setup and deployment.

[image]

In my main application (MyApplication), I have two winforms formA and formB.
formA is the default form which is shown whenever my application is opened.

In my setup and deployment project, under the Users' Programs Menu I created a folder to put the shortcut for my main application (which would open the formA by default from my main application)...

[image]

How can I also create a shortcut for my formB so that I could choose whether to run formA or formB?

EDIT 1:

I was aiming for this kind of setup:
  formA would be the main application.
  formB would be used to configure settings for formA

That's why I want to run formB independently from formA, so that I could choose to configure the settings for formA first before actually running formA

Answer (score 3):

Two options:

- Have two separate WinForms projects instead. Do you only ever need to show one form on each launch, or can the user switch between them? If they only ever want to see one *or* the other, then a separate app feels cleanest.
- Have a command line parameter which shows the other form instead. Then add a shortcut which includes that command line parameter. The code in your `Main` method would look something like this:

  ```
  Form form = args.Length == 1 && args[0] == "-otherForm"
      ? new OtherForm() 
      : new MainForm();
  Application.Run(form);
  ```

Comment: If I use two separate WinForm projects, could I still be able to access files and resources from one project to another? especially the app.config file?

Comment: @chad: You could definitely access resources (with a bit of care). I think you'd need different app.config files though. (I could be wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

In the Main method run a third form in your `Application.Run`. In this form you can have  radiobuttons or something for the user to select which form to run.

Comment: I already tried doing that one and its working sir, is there no way I could do it by making separate link that would launch each forms separately?